# Safari COOP and window.open don't work even on same origin

Tags: javascript, safari, same-origin-policy, window.open, window.opener

I am setting the `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy` (COOP) to 'same-origin' and I use `window.open` to open a window, while being within the same origin (user is located at `https://example.com/here`):

```js
// within a user-invoked event
const childWindow = window.open('https://example.com/there', 'child-window')
```

This works as expected on Chrome and FF, where I have knowledge about the child window's `location` and `closed` state and the child can access `window.opener`.

However, on Safari Desktop (and only there), it behaves as if the sites don't have the same origin:

```js
childWindow.closed // true
```

in the popup:

```js
window.opener // null
```

Setting the COOP header to `same-origin-allow-popups` won't change anything.

Is this expected behaviour and I simply misunderstood the whole concept or is Safari doing things it's own way (hello IE...)?

Edit/note:

Setting COOP to `unsafe-none` makes it all work but that's not a real solution, right?

Edit 2:

### System Info

MacOS `12.4`
Safari `15.5` (`17613.2.7.1.8`)

### Header info

```
Summary
URL: https://example.com/here
Status: 200
Source: Service Worker

Request
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Safari/605.1.15

Response
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-in-secure-requests;default-src 'self';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'sha256-<hereIsAHash>' 'sha256-<hereIsAnotherHash>';child-src 'self';connect-src 'self' https://example.com wss://example.com;font-src 'self' data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';frame-src *;img-src 'self' data: blob:;manifest-src 'self';media-src 'self';object-src 'self';sandbox allow-same-origin allow-downloads allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-scripts allow-forms allow-modals allow-presentation;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';worker-src 'self' blob:;base-uri 'self';script-src-attr 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin
Content-Encoding: gzip
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2022 08:46:17 GMT
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: nginx/1.21.6
x-download-options: noopen
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
expect-ct: max-age=604800, enforce
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains, max-age=31536000
origin-agent-cluster: ?1
```

### Helmet config

```js
const self = '\'self\''
const data = 'data:'
const blob = 'blob:'
const unsafeEval = '\'unsafe-eval\''
const unsafeInline = '\'unsafe-inline\''
const connectSrc = ['https://example.com', 'wss://example.com']
const externalHostUrls = ['https://foobar.com']

export const helmetOptions = {
    crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
    crossOriginOpenerPolicy: { policy: 'same-origin' },
    crossOriginResourcePolicy: { policy: 'cross-origin' },
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      blockAllMixedContent: true,
      directives: {
        upgradeInSecureRequests: [],
        defaultSrc: [self],
        scriptSrc: [
          self,
          // we use hashes to allow unsafeEval when using dynamic imports
          unsafeEval,
          `'sha256-${hashes[0]}'`,
          `'sha256-${hashes[1]}'`
        ],
        childSrc: [self],
        connectSrc: connectSrc.concat(externalHostUrls),
        fontSrc: [self, data],
        formAction: [self],
        frameAncestors: [self],
        frameSrc: ['*'],
        imgSrc: [self, data, blob].concat(externalHostUrls),
        manifestSrc: [self],
        mediaSrc: [self],
        objectSrc: [self],
        sandbox: [
          'allow-same-origin',
          'allow-downloads',
          'allow-orientation-lock',
          'allow-pointer-lock',
          'allow-popups',
          'allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox',
          'allow-scripts',
          'allow-forms',
          'allow-modals',
          'allow-presentation'
        ],
        styleSrc: [self, unsafeInline],
        workerSrc: [self, blob]
      }
    },
    strictTransportSecurity: {
      maxAge: 15552000,
      includeSubDomains: true,
      preload: false
    },
    referrerPolicy: {
      policy: 'no-referrer'
    },
    expectCt: {
      enforce: true,
      maxAge: 604800
    },
    frameguard: {
      action: 'sameorigin'
    },
    dnsPrefetchControl: {
      allow: false
    },
    permittedCrossDomainPolicies: {
      permittedPolicies: 'none'
    },
    hidePoweredBy: true
  }
}
```

Version: `helmet@6.0.0`

Comment: Thats really weird. I tried to replicate your problem with the given information but I could not really replicate it. It works all fine for me. What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Your added information helped me a lot. I updated my Safari to 15.6.1 (17613.3.9.1.16) and I am now facing a similar problem. The weird thing is that when I remove the `sandbox` option in the `Content-Security-Policy` header it works fine. Can you confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

It is great that you added the `helmet config` into your question's edit - that truly helps!

**My theory**

Relying on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/block-all-mixed-content) the `upgradeInSecureRequests` is deprecated and comes with several wranings. From the docs:

> Warning: This directive is marked as obsolete in the specification: all mixed content is now blocked if it can't be autoupgraded.

The fact that the compatibility table (at the bottom of the page) states that there is no clear evidence for safari support (rest of browsers have more concrete data) only makes it a strong suspect

I suggest that you set this setting in your `helmet config` to false and test it on `safari`. This should not effect other browsers

Comment: Thanks I didn't thought about this one. Let me check and get back to you